# Is there a way to use methods between classes?

Tags: java, swing, class, oop, methods

I have two .java files in the same package. I am planning on making the first .java file the underlying code and the second .java file the GUI swing interface.

My problem I encountered was when working on the GUI part of the project, I needed to access several methods from the .java file with the code. My .java file with the code is a like this:

```
    package same;
    public class HFSim extends ApplicationTemplate
   {
       private static class AppFrame extends ApplicationTemplate.AppFrame
          {

             public myMethodIWanttoUse()
                  {
                     //code
                  }
```

And in my GUI .java:

```
    package same;
    public class GUI extends JFrame
     {
       public GUI()
         {
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
            {
                 //this is where I want to use the method from above
```

Is there a way to get that method to be used in the GUI portion? Or is there a better way to approach this problem? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make `methodIWantToUse()` static by replacing

```
public myMethodIWanttoUse()
```

with

```
public static myMethodIWanttoUse()
```

Secondly, make `AppFrame` marked as `public` instead of `private`.

Then just call you method like this `HFSim.AppFrame.myMethodIWantToUse()`.

**Edit:**

Alternatively, you don't have to make your method `static`. Just add this in your GUI code:

```
HFSim.AppFrame frame = new HFSim.AppFrame();
frame.myMethodIWantToUse();
```

Still, no matter what, you have to make `AppFrame` be `public`.

Comment: Use of `static` is a sign of poor GUI design usually.

Answer (score 4):

You have multiple solutions to your problem. The first question you should answer is how these methods you need to call qualify themselves.

- Are they utility methods? (They don't require an instance of an object to work on)
- Are they attached to a single instance of an object?
- Do you need to call methods of a specific object more than just methods?

You can either:

- Declare them `static` and call them, eg `HFSim.AppFrame.myMethoIWanttoUse();`
- Declare a static instance of the object containing them, eg

  ```
  public class HFSim extends ApplicationTemplate {
    public static final AppFrame appFrame = new AppFrame();
    ...
  }    

  public class GUI extends JFrame {
    public GUI() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        HFSim.appFrame.myMethodIWanttoUse();
      }
    }
  }
  ```
- Pass the instance of the object to the other one:

  ```
  public class GUI extends JFrame {
    private final HFSim.AppFrame appFrame;

    public GUI(HFSim.AppFrame appFrame) { this.appFrame = appFrame; }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      appFrame.myMethodIWanttoUse();
    }
  }
  ```

Comment: *"Do you need to call methods of a specific object more than just methods?"*  ..What?  Which *"methods of a specific object"* are *"more than just methods"*?

Comment: @AndrewThompson: it was meant to mark the difference between calling methods on a specific given object, which is known a priori, or calling methods on any given object which could different. Both choices would require a different level on encapsulation to obtain the best trade-off between flexibility and being simple.

Comment: That explanation should be [part of the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/24563584/edit)!